# Fast multiplication times a fixed constant $A$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, fourier-analysis

Is there a way to speed up integer multiplication of billions of $B_{i}$'s times a fixed $A$?

We can configure $A$ to be either small compared to the $B_{i}$'s (e.g. $10^{10}$ compared to $10^{200}$) or else on the same order.

I am trying to find possibilities for precomputation and/or parallelism.

For example, if two of the $B_{i}$'s are "near" each other, we can do:

$$AB_{0} = AB_{0}$$
$$T = A(B_{1} - B_{0})$$
$$AB_{1} = T + AB_{0}$$

We still have two multiplications, but since $B_{1}$ and $B_{0}$ are close, one of the multiplications is smaller than it would be otherwise, though I'm not sure whether that is useful in practice. If any pair of $B_{i}$'s differ by $2^{k}$, then we have an obvious reduction. But this is rare and hard to identify.

Absent any other ideas for parallelism, we look at precomputation.

If we were using a digital circuit, we could omit (on average) half the partial products (i.e. those for which the corresponding bit in $A$ is $0$) and pack the adders to avoid them.

In software this might analog to a fixed sequence of binary shifts & adds. Using FFT multiplication, we could precompute $A$'s polynomial and FFT. But given the huge overhead of FFT multiplication this might only succeed in cutting down the overhead rather than reaping an advantage (?)

Any ideas or pointers (even far-fetched) would be appreciated. Are there any general strategies for algorithm optimization *besides* parallelism and precomputation? I'm trying to think outside the proverbial box.

Though only inspirationally-related, I was intrigued by Daniel Bernstein's parallel algorithm for [finding the smooth parts](http://cr.yp.to/factorization/smoothparts-20040510.pdf) of a large set of integers.

**Related question:**
[Number Theoretic Transform (NTT) to speed up multiplications](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182734/number-theoretic-transform-ntt-to-speed-up-multiplications)

If anyone thinks this question belongs on StackOverflow, let me know.

Comment: Have you tried any optimized software libraries for arbitrary large integers (say, for c/c++) and compared the running time of many multiplications done in a row to any of your ideas? It may in fact be very hard to beat those optimized libraries, even in your situation with billions of B. Also, as far as standard parallel computation goes, just distributing the B among multiple threads  is the obvious way to go.

Comment: I'm not aware of any MP libraries that cache or factor out computations common to repeated factors, though I suppose there's no reason why one of their algorithms couldn't be adapted to do that. Guess I was hoping for a viable number-theoretic or fourier trick. But altering LibTomMath might be the way to go. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Sure, if you can somehow modify something like GMP or LibTomMath then that could work, but basically what I was saying was, since the libraries like GMP are already so optimized anyway, at a very low level very close to the hardware (e.g. GMP uses assembly code written routines, basically direct machine code using the CPU registers etc. in the best way possible) maybe it'll be really hard to make a program any noticeably faster than simply multiplying every B by A (say, using GMP), whether you try to beat it by modifying a library or just starting from scratch.

Comment: You may be right, but unfortunately I'm an incorrigible optimist :)